# Is Jordan outer measure finitely additive on positively separated sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to argue that exterior measure has nice properties that Jordan outer measure doesn't have. One of them is finite additivity, but I can't find a simple way to show Jordan outer measure is not finitely additive on positively separated sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$? Can someone give me a simple proof or a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is finitely additive for separated sets.  A sufficiently small cube can not 
cut both sets.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean. Do you mean positively separated? And what do you mean by "cutting both sets"?

Comment: One way to compute the Jordan measure is to divide $\mathbb R^n$ into a mesh of small cubes of side $\delta$, and count how many of the cubes cut the set (that is, have non-empty intersection with the set).  Multiply by the volume $\delta^n$, take the limit as $\delta \to 0$.  If two sets are positively separated, then for small enough $\delta$ this is additive, so in the limit this is additive.

Comment: Cutting a set = the intersection with this set is non empty.
You asked for "positively separated sets". I understodd that the 
infimum of the distances between points one of each set is greater than a certain $d  > 0$.  I called this separated sets in my answer.

So my answer is  the same  as Edgar.